# How to have a maximum number of replacement when sampling in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to sample a list of numbers with replacement. I would like to have a hard cap on the number of times a number is chosen. For instance:

```
x=sample(1:20, 10, replace = TRUE)
[1] 17  5 11 13  5 11 14  11 10 11
```

In this case the number 11 has a frequency of 4.
Is there a way that I can for that frequency to be 2 or less?

Comment: Maybe `sample(c(1:20,1:20), 10, replace = FALSE)`?

Comment: Why do you want to cap the frequency of an element if you're randomly sampling? It's likely that there's a better way to go about this, depending on your situation.

Comment: @brittenb   In my dataframe, each row represents a person, and I have a column with houses unique id. If this Id is sampled twice, that means two people live in that house. I need to cap this number so i can control the maximum number of persons that live in a house.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are actually looking for a random assignment of people to houses.  This could be done by putting two ids for each house into a vector, generate a random permutation of the vector and then assign each entry to a person.

```
houseIds <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
houseSamples <- sample(rep(houseIds, 2), 8) #where 8 is the number of people
```